# AngularJS Login form submits partial password

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ng-submit

I am using AngularJS login form. I noticed that 1/10 times that the password is being sent partially if the user pressed the enter key really quickly. For example, if the password is "happygolucky", it will send instead "happy."

I can't seem to find a similar problem posted elsewhere and am at a lost as to why it occurs in the first place.

This is the form that I am using:

```
<form name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="loginFormDirectiveCtrl.login()">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': loginForm.email.$dirty && loginForm.email.$error.required }">
        <label for="email">Company Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-model="loginFormDirectiveCtrl.email"
               required/>
        <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$dirty && loginForm.email.$error.required"
              class="help-block">Company email is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"
         ng-class="{ 'has-error': loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required }">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control"
               ng-model="loginFormDirectiveCtrl.password" required/>
        <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required"
              class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
    <button class="login-button" type="submit"
            ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid || loginFormDirectiveCtrl.loading">
        <span ng-hide="loginFormDirectiveCtrl.loading">LOGIN</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: i have same experience but when used an codebar pistols who on every read it also send an enter key.  But not when user normally type and enter so quickly.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco Can you elaborate what you mean? In your case, the password includes a new line character when there is a codebar pistols? And what is a codebar pistols if you don't mind explaining? Thanks!

Comment: i mean, i have a similar situation with a texbox sku, when an article is scanned with a pistol. it also fire the submit, and sometimes sku are very large and i trigger the submit befere the ng-model completes. thats what a i mean.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco I see. Unfortunately, I do not have a situation with a textbox sku, but I will double check if there is something else that fires the submission before ng-model completes. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: not fire twice i mean if sku was 100002 some times sends 1000 like in your password.

Comment: Gotcha. I will look into what causes the submission before ng-model completes.

Answer (score 1):

What a do for the example i told in the comments was creating a directive. like this.

```
.directive('inputDelayEnter', ['$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {        
        require:'^?ngModel', 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.bind('keydown keypress', function (event) { 
                if(event.which === 13) {                    
                     $timeout(500);
                    if(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue !== undefined){
                      scope.$apply(function (){
                          scope.$eval(attrs.coppelDelayEnter);
                      });
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    };
  }
])​;
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.sku" input-delay-enter>
```

i think it can help if you only change type to password.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now. Let me try it out.